# C++ override operator<< in inherited class

Tags: c++, stream, operator-overloading

I have a base class where the overriding of an << operator is made.

```
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Animal& animal);
    ostream & operator<<(ostream & out, const Animal& animal)
{
    out << animal.age << "," << animal.size << endl;
}
```

This is in the .h of my Abonne class. I have a inherited class of this Abonne class named Etudiant. I wish to override the << operator in the Etudiant class again, but I want it to call the operator<< of the base class Abonne in the definition of the Etudiant class, plus add more. I tried this:

```
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Dog& dog);

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Dog& dog)
{
    return out << dog << endl;
}
```

It's not working, recalling the << of itself and recursiving till it crashes.

How should I proceed?

Thank you.

Comment: _"I have a base class that contains the override of the << operator as a global function"_ Everything about this statement is wrong.

Comment: Create a `put()` function that can be used with a class qualifier.

Answer (score 0):

Easy! You need to invoke the version that takes an `Abonne`. So simply do that:

```
return out << static_cast<const Abonne&>(etudiant) << " ... and more" << endl;
//            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thank you :) Do you know another way without casting? Abonne::operator<< would not work, because the function is global?

Comment: Do you know if it would have been ok in a case where the function is not global?

Comment: @TheBlueWizard: It would.